# TFS 2015 plugin - multiple task inputs

Tags: tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm writing a plugin for TFS 2015 and i'm trying to create a task that uses an input that may repeat itself several times dynamically.
Each time the user enters such an input I will add another field (of the same type) to the task.

So actually I'm talking about the possibility of "n" inputs of some type.
Is there a way to create such inputs (kind of a dynamic array of inputs) in the task.json file?

Comment: Why you need to achieve this? Seems impossible. However, there maybe some workaround to achieve your fundamental purpose.

Comment: I want the user to enter a list of items (complex items, so a list separated by commas is overruled). The user may enter one or ten or fifty items, hence the dynamic list...

Comment: Is it a build task?

Comment: Yes. it's a build task.

Comment: Sample is coming for creating your own UI for a muliline: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/55149/is-there-a-way-to-create-fields-dynamically-for-a.html

Comment: Or in more detail: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/216666/view.html

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to achieve this feature. The alternative way would set the input type to "multiLine" and enter your items in several lines. And then you can get these items via getDelimitedInpu() method with "\n" delim.

```
import tl = require('vsts-task-lib');
var items:string[] = tl.getDelimitedInput('items','\n');
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm already using that approach. I was trying to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Unfortunately there is none. You could create 10 inputs and then have 2 show up if 1 isn't empty, 3 show up if 2 isn't empty, 4 show up if 3 isn't empty... It's not going to be pretty to setup, but it'll work...